# How to get intel GPU drivers working on Optimus laptop?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics, optimus

I'm at my wit's end with this, I've been grappling with a variant of this problem for about a year now.
Essentially I have an NVIDIA Optimus laptop, and when switching to the Intel GPU via NVIDIA Prime, the machine would just freeze upon logging out. The only way to boot the system from then onwards was to use `nomodeset`.

I've made some progress based on hours of research. Currently I have a clean installation of 18.2. The first thing I did was update the kernel to 4.10.0-35-generic, which at the time was the latest that showed as a recommended update in Update Manager. Then I installed the NVIDIA and Intel Microcode drivers via the Driver Manager. Booting the system with the NVIDIA GPU selected by default, I switched to Intel and the machine froze on logout, and refused to load the login screen after reboot. Business as usual. It should be noted that I doubt the kernel update is causing this as I had identical behaviour with the default kernel. In fact it has been suggested that the 4.10 kernel might fix some of these issues, but not in my case.
I then decided to boot again with the nomodeset option and was able to reach a desktop. Once this was done I installed the Intel GPU drivers using [this guide](https://mintguide.org/system/73-intel-linux-graphics-drivers-installer-for-linux.html). Everything was successful, but I still cannot boot without disabling hardware acceleration. It gets past the splash screen, and then hangs with this output on the screen, and will not respond to anything other than a forced shutdown with the power button.

```
[    8.836398] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 timeout
[    8.836446] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
```

My laptop's Bluetooth has no hardware switch so I cannot disable it. Sometimes, with the old kernel, I would have a similar message on shutdown if running the Intel GPU.

`inxi -Fxz` output (with nomodeset)

```
System:    Host: kyle-mint Kernel: 4.10.0-35-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
       Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.6 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
       Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Machine:   System: PC Specialist Limited (portable) product: N15_17RF
       Mobo: CLEVO model: N15_17RF
       Bios: American Megatrends v: 1.05.02 date: 01/04/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-6440HQ (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
       flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 20736
       clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 879 MHz 2: 833 MHz 3: 800 MHz
       4: 893 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
       Card-2: NVIDIA GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
       Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: fbdev (unloaded: vesa) FAILED: intel,nouveau
       Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-35-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 02:00.0
       IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
       Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
Controller
       driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.1
       IF: enp3s0f1 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 878.2GB (1.6% used)
       ID-1: /dev/sda model: BIWIN_SSD size: 128.0GB
       ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD7500BPKX size: 750.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 28G used: 5.7G (22%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
       ID-2: /boot size: 276M used: 121M (46%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda1
       ID-3: /home size: 275G used: 125M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb6
       ID-4: swap-1 size: 8.19GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdb7
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 65.0C mobo: N/A
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 213 Uptime: 2 min Memory: 951.9/7899.8MB
       Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
       Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

The guys at the Linux Mint forums advised me to try [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/3#TOC-Improve-video-performance-for-Intel-graphics), but to no avail.
Is there anything else I might be able to try? Would I have better luck with vanilla Ubuntu as opposed to Linux Mint, or even a completely different distro?
I do not have the ability to switch off one of the GPUs in the BIOS for diagnostics.

I've also tried a clean install and followed [this guide](https://www.pcsuggest.com/nvidia-optimus-ubuntu/) to install Bumblebee, but again the machine refuses to boot when hardware acceleration is enabled, and even when disabled (it just freezes on the splash screen, with no output if I remove `quiet splash` from the boot options). The key here seems to be getting the machine to run on the intel GPU at all, before trying any voodoo with Optimus.

I've had this machine semi-running with Mint 17.3 in the past so it's not the hardware at fault here, it seems to be the driver or whatever is failing at the point the OS tries to use the intel GPU.

TL;DR: I need to get the intel integrated graphics drivers working in Linux Mint 18.2 on an Optimus laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done yet, supply your BIOS information the following way:

To gather information about the laptop model, install dmidecode. For the DSDT/SSDT
files, install the acpidump and iasl tools:

```
sudo apt-get install acpidump iasl dmidecode
```

or (on Fedora):

```
sudo yum install pmtools iasl dmidecode
```

Then use the script from http://lekensteyn.nl/files/get-acpi-info.sh to create the
tarball containing information about the laptop model, PCI hardware and ACPI tables.
To do so, run the following commands in a terminal:

```
wget http://lekensteyn.nl/files/get-acpi-info.sh
sh get-acpi-info.sh
```

This will create a tar.gz file that you can attach to the bug report. In the comment
itself, please include a link to the product page of the model (if available).